# How to print original,duplicate and triplicate copies of a page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sample html  page where i want to print only three copies of this page and also change original(mentioned in right top corner)  to duplicate only if we take a 2nd copy of this page. Is there anyway by which can we achieve this using Javascript or Jquery?

```js
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
```

```css
 .original  {
float : right;
margin-right : -0.1cm;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
       <div class="col-xs-1 original"><font color="red"><strong>Original</strong></font></div>
```

Comment: I think at most you’ll be able to count how many times your `myFunction` was called; but that does of course not mean that anything was actually printed, the user could simply cancel the dialog. Or they might instead print two dozen copies in one go, simply by entering that number in the dialog. There is no way for you to know this using JS that runs in the context of a normal web page.

Comment: Getting one “original” and two “copies” printed in one go could be kinda possible, though ... if you clone the document content via JS, append it two more times (how much that gets you in trouble regarding stuff like duplicate ids etc., you’d have to see), and then use a print stylesheet to control stuff like where page breaks occur ...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to give simple solution which holds flag of print count temporarily. Please check below.

```js
var v1=0;
function myFunction() {
   if (v1==0) {
  window.print();
   }
   else {
  window.print();
  $('#s1').text('Duplicate');
   }
   v1++;
}
```

```css
.original  {
float : right;
margin-right : -0.1cm;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
       <div class="col-xs-1 original"><font color="red"><strong id="s1" >Original</strong></font></div>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried your code but if we use cancel in print window and again click on print it will show as duplicate. Can't we have a condition where original should change to duplicate only if we take a printout of original copy?

Comment: Sadly, window.print() doesn't return any value. So, there's no way to know if the user clicked Save or Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Here, The sample Code.  Pls Check now.

```
    #printable { display: none; }

    @media print
    {
        #non-printable { display: none; }
        #printable { display: block; }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="non-printable">
        Your normal page contents
    </div>
    <div id="printable">
        Printer version <div id="count"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="autoclick" onclick="window.print();">Print<a>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

    var beforePrint = function() {
        console.log('Functionality to run before printing.');
    };

    var afterPrint = function() {
        console.log('Functionality to run after printing');
          var vals = $('#inc').val();
          var incval = parseInt(vals)+parseInt(1);
           $('#inc').val(incval);
           if(incval < 3)
           {   

              window.setTimeout('window.print()',5000); 
           }
    };

    if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                beforePrint();
            } else {
                afterPrint();
            }
        });
    }

    window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;

}());
</script>
<input type="text" id="inc" value="0">
```